# ajax done or fail fire before server response

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I have a problem, when I use ajax post data into my express(nodejs) server, I have a call back function in server side, after complete DB access, then response to client ajax.
But, I found, before my server call back function complete, The ajax .fail will fire. I have try to setup timeout 10000, but, ajax .fail always fire directly.

Server: Express(Node.js)
Client: JQuery(3.2.1) post by ajax

ajax code:

```
    $('#createNewGroup').click(function() {
        $('#loading').show();

        $.ajax({
           url: 'list_live_createNewGroup',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false,
           data: {  groupname: $('#groupname').val(),
                    groupdesc: $('#groupdesc').val(),
                    grouplocation: $('#grouplocation').val(),
                    accountname: $('#accountname').val(),
                    accountid: $('#accountid').val(),
                    bankname:  $('#bankname').val() }})
        .done(function(data) {

            $('#loading').hide();

            window.location.hash = '#mygroups';
            window.location.reload(true);
        })
        .always(function(data) {

        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $('#loading').hide();

            var response = JSON.parse(data["responseText"]);
            alert(response["msg"]);

            window.location.href = "list#creategroup";

        });
    });
```

server side code:

```
router.post('/list_live_createNewGroup', tools.checkUserLogin, function(request, response) {
    var currentUser = new Parse.User();
    currentUser.id = request.session.user;

    .......

    newUserGroup.save(null, {
        success: function(newUserGroup)  {

            response.json(true);
        },
        error: function(newUserGroup, error) {
            response.json(true);
        }
    });



});
```

Comment: `tools.checkUserLogin` might be returning some response.

Comment: I removed tools.checkUserLogin, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after do some modification, I figure out the real problem.
In order to I use JQuery to control Button to post information to server side. But, my html  write

```
<input type="submit" id="createNewGroup">
```

input type "submit" will confuse JQuery to do other things. Therefore, I had changed my input type to button, the problem is solved.